# How do we script/automate an Electron app with Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, automation, electron, puppeteer, e2e-testing

Is it possible? Is there a guide somewhere? Basically I'd like to do E2E testing of an Electron app, and will script user interactions, i.e. make a "bot" or "puppet" user that interacts inside the Electron app.

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: It's been 6+ months and there are workarounds that can allow you to control the BrowserWindow with puppeteer to certain extent.

If you are doing E2E testing, I still recommend spectron because that's what listed on electron website.

You will need `puppeteer-in-electron` and `puppeteer-core`,

```
const { BrowserWindow, app } = require("electron")
const pie = require("puppeteer-in-electron")
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-core");

const main = async () => {
  const browser = await pie.connect(app, puppeteer);

  const window = new BrowserWindow();
  const url = "about:blank";
  await window.loadURL(url);

  const page = await pie.getPage(browser, window);

  // here is your page to control
  await page.goto('https://example.net');
  console.log(await page.title()); // should print Example Domain

  // use the following instead of browser.close or disconnect
  window.destroy();
};

main();
```

There are also other experimental solutions available right now, but not guaranteed to work with all puppeteer API's.

- [puppeteer-electron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-electron)

---

Previous answer below,

Not related to puppeteer, but Electron has spectron, which allows you to test electron apps using chrome driver, head to their [home page.](https://electronjs.org/spectron) and [api doc](https://github.com/electron/spectron#application-api).

Spectron was built on top of ChromeDriver and WebDriverIO. So if you are already using puppeteer, the syntax and usage will feel familiar.

## Quick Start Spectron

Commands to get you started fast,

```
mkdir electron-test && cd electron-test    
git clone https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start
yarn init -y
yarn add -D spectron mocha
```

So, we have spectron, mocha and the quickstart file inside that folder. Now let's create some spec on `test/spec.js` path.

```
const Application = require("spectron").Application;
const assert = require("assert");

describe("Verify a visible window is opened with a title", function() {
  before(async function() {
    this.app = new Application({
      // your app or electron executable path
      path: "node_modules/electron/dist/electron",
      // path to main.js file location
      args: ["electron-quick-start/"]
    });
    await this.app.start();
  });
  after(async function() {
    this.app.stop();
  });

  it("is visible", async function() {
    const isVisible = await this.app.browserWindow.isVisible();
    assert.equal(isVisible, true);
  });

  it("gets the title", async function() {
    const title = await this.app.client.getTitle();
    assert.equal(title, "Hello World!");
  });
});
```

Let's run it,

```
➜  electron-test ./node_modules/.bin/mocha


  Verify a visible window is opened with a title
    ✓ is visible
    ✓ gets the title


  2 passing (665ms)
```

Comment: I'm contemplating using Spectron, but was curious about Puppeteer, to make it possible to re-use Puppeteer code with some other projects already using Puppeteer.

Comment: Can you list them?

Comment: They're just various private projects at the moment, not open source. They aren't using Electron, just web apps.

Comment: Puppeteer was not made for electron, and I did not find anyone using puppeteer for mocking electron. Spectron was made for electron and I find plenty of resources for that. Shouldn't I go with spectron?

Comment: Spectron seems to be deprecated.